# How to make UIPageViewController slide automatically with endless repeat?

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

How can i make my UIPageViewController automatically slide images?

I've created and implemented everything, now I would like for it to slide images automatically with time interval of 10 seconds...

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: you should show some effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class that manages your UIPageViewController :

Have a property like

```
@property NSInteger currentIndex;
```

Instanciate it at 0, and everytime you change to another viewController, update its value (_currentIndex++ / _currentIndex--)

Then instanciate a NSTimer :

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(changeController:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];
```

And add this method

```
- (void) changeController:(NSTimer*)timer
{
   UIViewController yourViewController = [self itemControllerForIndex: self.currentIndex+1];
   self.currentIndex++;
   NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:yourViewController] 
   [yourPageViewController setViewControllers:array direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to call the `- setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` method each time you want to change the page.

You could use a `NSTimer` to fire your own intermediate method that sets the corresponding page using the aforementioned method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
- (UIViewController *) pageViewController: (UIPageViewController *) pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *) viewController
    {
        HelpPageViewController *itemController = (HelpPageViewController *) viewController;

        if (itemController.itemIndex > 0)
        {
            return [self itemControllerForIndex: itemController.itemIndex-1]; // bilo je -1
        }



       return nil;

        }

    - (UIViewController *) pageViewController: (UIPageViewController *) pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *) viewController
    {
        HelpPageViewController *itemController = (HelpPageViewController *) viewController;

        if (itemController.itemIndex+1 < [contentImages count]) // bilo je <
        {
            return [self itemControllerForIndex: itemController.itemIndex+1];
        }

        return nil;


    }

    UIPageViewController *scrollingHeader = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ScrollingHeader"];
        scrollingHeader.dataSource = self;

        if([contentImages count])
        {


            NSArray *startingViewControllers = @[[self itemControllerForIndex: 0]];
            [scrollingHeader setViewControllers: startingViewControllers
                                     direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward

                                      animated: NO
                                    completion: nil];
        }

        self.pageViewController = scrollingHeader;
        [self addChildViewController: self.pageViewController];
        [self.view addSubview: self.pageViewController.view];



        [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController: self];
```